# Query string based commands and browser back button

Tags: php, string, url

I have a dynamic "product.php" page with a "cart" function in it.

The product information is fetched from a database depending on the product ID specified in query string like this

```
http://www.website.com/product.php?product=1101
```

The "Add to cart" button link is :

```
http://www.website.com/product.php?product=1101&action=add
```

The "product.php" page always get the value from "action". The "cart" function uses this value to perform the corresponding action (add, delete, etc). The "action" value is also used to change the "Add to cart" button into a non-clickable "Added to cart".

Everything works great, BUT :

When a user press the back button after adding a product to the cart, since the page was re-generated with a different URL, he gets back to the first one with the clickable button.

- It gives the impression the product has been removed from cart.
- User has to click the "back" button 2 times to continue shopping.

Any ideas on how to prevent the first page to be shown when the "back" button is pressed ?

Comment: Just let's check in the `product.php`, is the item added to the cart or not. If yes, then do not show the button. So simple.

Comment: You did not understant the point of my question.